# Definition of differentiability for multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In multivariable calculus, we say $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $x_0 \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d $, $U$ open if there exists a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - T(h)}{||h||} = 0 $$

MY question: Why does it follow that $T$ is defined as

$$ T(x) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{ f(x_0 + tx) - f(x_0) }{t } $$

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f \, : \, U \subset \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}^m$ differentiable at $x_{0}$ (with $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^d$). The definition of differentiability at $x_{0}$ you gave is equivalent to :

$$ f(x_{0}+h) = f(x_{0}) + T_{x_{0}}f(h) + \Vert h \Vert \varepsilon(h) $$

(since the linear map $T$ depends on $f$ and $x_{0}$, I'd rather write $T_{x_{0}}f(h)$ instead of $T(h)$) where $\varepsilon$ is a function such that : $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \varepsilon(h) = 0$. Now, take $v$ in $U$. For $t$ "small enough", letting $h=tv$ in the definition gives :

$$ f(x_{0}+tv) = f(x_{0}) + T_{x_{0}}f \big( tv \big) + \Vert tv \Vert \varepsilon(tv) $$

Since $T_{x_{0}}f$ is linear, it re-writes :

$$ f(x_{0}+tv) = f(x_{0}) + t T_{x_{0}}f(v) + \vert t \vert \Vert v \Vert \varepsilon(tv) $$

Using $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{t \to 0} \varepsilon(tv) = 0$, eventually, you get :

$$ T_{x_{0}}f(v) = \lim \limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+tv) - f(x_{0})}{t} $$

Answer (score 0):

Using your definition,

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)-T(tx)}{|tx|} = 0
$$
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{|tx|} - \frac{T(tx)}{|tx|}  = 0
$$
$$
\frac{1}{|x|}\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{|t|} - \frac{tT(x)}{|t|}  = 0
$$
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{|t|} - \frac{tT(x)}{|t|}  = 0
$$

If $t>0$ we have:

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{t} - \frac{tT(x)}{t}  = 0
$$

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{t} - T(x)  = 0
$$

$$
T(x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{t}
$$

if $t<0$ we have

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tx) - f(x_0)}{-t} - \frac{tT(x)}{-t}  = 0
$$

which leads to the same conclusion.